# What's the best module to access SimpleDB in python?

Tags: python, amazon-simpledb

I'm writing a python script to select, insert, update, and delete data in SimpleDB.

I've been using the simpledb module written by sixapart so far, and it's working pretty well.

I've found one potential bug/feature that is problematic for me when running select queries with "limit", and I'm thinking of trying it with the boto module to see if it works better.

Has anyone used these two modules? Care to offer an opinion on which is better?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found boto to be effective and straight forward and I've never had any trouble with queries with limits. Although I've never used the sixapart module.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Based on this thread I think I may hit the same limit issue in boto, but glad to have an endorsement of it nonetheless: http://groups.google.com/group/boto-users/browse_frm/thread/2a627fd9962e5464